# databricks overwriting entire table instead of adding new partition

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `db`.`customer_history` (
  `name` STRING,
  `addrress` STRING, 
  `filename` STRING,
  `dt` DATE)
USING delta
PARTITIONED BY (dt)
```

When I use this to load a partition data to the table

```
      df
    .write
    .partitionBy("dt")
    .mode("overwrite")
    .format("delta")
    .saveAsTable("db.customer_history")
```

For some reason, it overwrites the entire table. I thought the overwrite mode only overwrites the partition data (if it exists). Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta makes it easy to update certain disk partitions with the `replaceWhere` option. You can selectively overwrite only the data that matches predicates over partition columns as like this ,

```
dataset.write.repartition(1)\
       .format("delta")\
       .mode("overwrite")\
       .partitionBy('Year','Week')\
       .option("replaceWhere", "Year == '2019' AND Week >='01' AND Week <='02'")\ #to avoid overwriting Week3
       .save("\curataed\dataset")
```

Note : replaceWhere is particularly useful when you have to run a computationally expensive algorithm, but only on certain partitions'

You can ref : [link](https://mungingdata.com/delta-lake/updating-partitions-with-replacewhere/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to overwrite a single partition, use:

```
df
  .write 
  .format("delta") 
  .mode("overwrite") 
  .option("replaceWhere", "dt >= '2021-01-01'") 
  .save("data_path")
```